# creating unlockable content for educational form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am currently creating an web-app for a small based company. This company specializes in courses for people who are bad in english and want to get better at it. However i am now trying to make a form, and if it is completed correctly, it will give acces to another form.

So I've got 10 questions in lesson 1, and if all 10 are answered correrctly, Lesson 2, and the test for lesson 1, will be unlocked. So when the lesson is fulfilled, the test will be unlocked, and the next lesson (Image will go from a locked lock, to an opened lock too)(at least that is the idea)

Any one has a clue on how to do this? if there are any more questions about this, please ask me.

Greetings,

[screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKAfq.png)

[another screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a79Ie.png)

Comment: Just get user input ( eg. Answer ) compare with the one in database and if is correct-> next if not user will need to answer again. Same with the lock icon. If all are correct unlock otherwise - lock.

Comment: Perhaps show us what you have tried? You expect us to write the code from scratch for you?

Comment: We are here to help you whenever you are struck with any issues. not for providing ideas. If you want any ideas please hire programmer to do that.

Comment: You need to show us atleast what you have tried.

Comment: First of all, thank you guys for the quick response. Second is that i am still learning how to make these kind of things, I am not good at it, at least tat is what i think. i have nothing yet prepared because i simply dont know where to start. the only thing i have to show u guys is a web app, which i have some screenshots of. Or if you really want to help, we can maybe talk about getting the passwords for the app. So you can have a better look.

Answer (score 0):

some pseudo code to show the thought process that goes behind a function like this:

```
var correct = 0;

printAllQuestionsToScreen(questions[0]);

OnEvent.click('question') {
    if (this.answer == question['questionID'].answer) {
        correct++;
        this.answer.class('correct') //change color or something to indicate it's correct
    }
    if(correct = number of questions) {
        correct = 0;
        printAllQuestionsToScreen(questions[1]);
    }
}
```